# How can I strip text formatting tags using beautiful soup 4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been learning to use BeautifulSoup4 and have had good success so far. I'm doing a [practice problem](https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/07/14/19-decode-a-web-page-two.html) on [practicepython.org](https://practicepython.org) to print an article's text body out to a file.

Through inspecting the HTML tags, I was able to locate the CSS class under which all paragraphs of text fall, and then iterate through those tags to get all of the 'p' tags.

```
   url = 'http://www.vanityfair.com/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture'
    r = req.get(url)
    r_html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, 'html.parser')

    with open('html_to_text.txt', 'w') as open_file:
        for stuff in soup.find_all('div', class_='grid--item body body__container article__body grid-layout__content'):
            for par in stuff.find_all('p'):
                print(par.string)
```

The issue is in the `print(par.string)` line at the bottom. According to [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), if a tag has multiple children (other tags and/or text strings) then the .string attribute is set to `None`, which is exactly what is happening.

I believe this is because inside some of the paragraphs, there is formatting tags like bold, underline, italics.

Does BeautifulSoup have a way to strip all of these so that I can print out the full text of the article without a lot of `None`'s popping up where there is formatted text?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings): **If there’s more than one thing inside a tag, you can still look at just the strings. Use the `.strings` generator:**

Comment: @Barmar, jeez one line down from where I left off reading. Thanks.